# Spark: convert rdd[row] to dataframe where one of the columns in the row is a list

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a rdd[row] with the following data for each row

```
[guid, List(peopleObjects)]  
["123", List(peopleObjects1, peopleObjects2, peopleObjects3)]
```

I want to convert this to a dataframe
I am using the following code

```
val personStructureType = new StructType()
    .add(StructField("guid", StringType, true))
    .add(StructField("personList", StringType, true))  
val personDF = hiveContext.createDataFrame(personRDD, personStructureType)
```

Should I be using a different datatype for my schema instead of StringType?

If my list is just a string it works but when its a List I get the following error

```
scala.MatchError: List(personObject1, personObject2, personObject3) (of class scala.collection.immutable.$colon$colon)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.CatalystTypeConverters$StringConverter$.toCatalystImpl(CatalystTypeConverters.scala:295)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.CatalystTypeConverters$StringConverter$.toCatalystImpl(CatalystTypeConverters.scala:294)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.CatalystTypeConverters$CatalystTypeConverter.toCatalyst(CatalystTypeConverters.scala:102)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.CatalystTypeConverters$StructConverter.toCatalystImpl(CatalystTypeConverters.scala:260)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.CatalystTypeConverters$StructConverter.toCatalystImpl(CatalystTypeConverters.scala:250)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.CatalystTypeConverters$CatalystTypeConverter.toCatalyst(CatalystTypeConverters.scala:102)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.CatalystTypeConverters$$anonfun$createToCatalystConverter$2.apply(CatalystTypeConverters.scala:401)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext$$anonfun$7.apply(SQLContext.scala:445)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext$$anonfun$7.apply(SQLContext.scala:445)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:328)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:328)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:328)
    at org.apache.spark.util.collection.ExternalSorter.insertAll(ExternalSorter.scala:219)
    at org.apache.spark.shuffle.sort.SortShuffleWriter.write(SortShuffleWriter.scala:73)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:73)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:41)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:88)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:214)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: What type is `peopleObject`? If it's a `case class`, can you include its definition? Even better would be some sample code that creates your `RDD`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not entirely clear what you are trying to do, but a better way to do what you are trying to do is to create a `case class` and then just map your `RDD` lines to the `case class`, then call `toDF`.

Something like:

```
case class MyClass(guid: Int, peopleObjects: List[String])

val rdd = sc.parallelize(Array((123,List("a","b")),(1232,List("b","d"))))

val df =  rdd.map(r => MyClass(r._1, r._2)).toDF
df.show
+----+-------------+
|guid|peopleObjects|
+----+-------------+
| 123|       [a, b]|
|1232|       [b, d]|
+----+-------------+
```

Or you can do it the long-hand way, but without using the case class, like this:

```
val df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(
  rdd.map(r => Row(r._1, r._2)),
  StructType(Array(
    StructField("guid",IntegerType),
    StructField("peopleObjects", ArrayType(StringType))
  ))
)
```

Comment: Thanks David. This has helped me gain some understanding. The peopleObjects class has properties like name & location. I was hoping to be able to pass the list of peopleObjects as the type into the dataframe. That way I do not have to teardown and rebuild the object when I want to create my final output format.  Right now I have a guid associated with a peopleObject, I groupbykey on the guid to get a list of peopleObject's. I plan on doing this same behavior on numerous tables then joining them all by the guid. Then creating a final output in a particular format.

Comment: Right now I am just creating json objects, passing that in as a string and doing all of my joins. Then rebuilding the objects back up, modifying the json and creating my final output.

Comment: This is a correct and helpful answer. @JohnEngelhart you should accept it.